# angular modify a select element's text on change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to modify a select element so that the selected text is always appended with the same text.

It's a pagination select, and I want it to include 'of '. So: the selector will always look like these examples:

```
[1 of 4]
1
2
3
4


[3 of 4]
1
2
3
4
```

At the moment, all I'm trying to do is get hold of the select element when it changes. I can't even do that!

The element is the `<select>` in my pagination.html template.
The methods are 
`$scope.update` (which does not fire) 
and 
`$scope.$watch('gridOptions.paginationCurrentPage')` (which does fire,  but has no ref to the control)

http://plnkr.co/edit/1GFuaLZQyPUfPylDhS2d?p=preview

How can I

1. get hold of the control, and/or
2. modify it to add 'of ' to ONLY the value in the box?

Comment: You don't seem to have a `select` - you have a `ui-grid` element. What do you mean by "get a hold"? And also, why?

Comment: [1] The ui-grid element is a select control, with options and everything.   
[2] I want a reference to it in JavaScript when it changes, so I can edit its innerHTML and add the 'of 4'.   
[3] Because the ui-grid control, with its "/4" is hideous-looking.   
[4] Also, obviously I am not using Markdown correctly, or these comments would all be on separate lines.

Comment: The ui-grid is a grid element, not a select element. It has a select, but its template does not seem have any hooks to change it. If you intend to "get a hold" via some jQuery selector, then I strongly recommend against that - just a bad practice that will give you headaches. And finally, the link you have, actually shows "1 of 4" (rather than "/4"), so I'm not even sure what you want changed